# Getting Rows From a CSV by Date

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file with several rows and a date column. I want to grab all rows that have a date is more than 30 days old. Here is my best attempt:

```
$Data = Import-CSV "H:\Data.csv"
$CutoffDate = (Get-Data).AddDays(-30)
$Data | Where-Object {$_.Date -lt $CutoffDate}
```

This does not return anything and there are definately rows with dates older than 30 days. My guess is that `$_.Date` is not recognized as a date, but that being the case I'm stumped on how to make it do so. Can anybody point me in the right direction here? Thanks. -Al

Comment: What is the format of the data in the Date column?

Comment: Is `Get-Data` a typo in your post here, or is it in your script as well? It should be `Get-Date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import data using `Import-CSV`, all properties are created as strings. To filter by date, you need to make the date a `datetime` object. The sample had a typo on the second line ( `Get-Data` instead of `Get-Date` ) too. Try this:

```
$Data = Import-CSV "H:\Data.csv"
$CutoffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$Data | Where-Object {$_.Date -as [datetime] -lt $CutoffDate}
```

You could combine it with `Import-CSV` if you want, like this:

```
$CutoffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$Data = Import-CSV "H:\Data.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Date -as [datetime] -lt $CutoffDate}
```